# How can I select this specific line in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="icons">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook" alt="facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter" alt="twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
</div>
```

I would like to position each icon in the div seperately, how could I select the icons seperately in CSS? 
`.icons a {` edits all of the icons in the div so I have no control over the positioning.

Comment: You're asking how to select immediate children of an element. I see that you're new to this, so please make sure you search through previous questions before you ask.

Comment: Why are you putting the icons in one div, if you want to position them separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use first-child and last-child.

```
.icons a:first-child { color: red; } // just affects facebook-link
.icons a:last-child { color: blue; } // just affects twitter-link
```

iIf there were more than two children you could use `:nth-child(x)`

also you could simply style the links directly by class:

```
.icons a.fa-twitter { }
```

Comment: Lots of good answers but this worked for me just like I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to target each anchor tag independently (and you don't want to use the handy classes you already have in there[1]), you can use the nth-child pseudo selector:

```css
.icons > a:nth-child(1){background:red;}
.icons > a:nth-child(2){background:green;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="icons">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook" alt="facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter" alt="twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
</div>
```

Check [browser support for nth-child](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

[1]: You are using fontawesome `fa-facebook` and `fa-twitter` classes, why not select those?

```css
.icons > a.fa-facebook{background:red;}
.icons > a.fa-twitter{background:green;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://opensource.keycdn.com/fontawesome/4.7.0/font-awesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-dNpIIXE8U05kAbPhy3G1cz+yZmTzA6CY8Vg/u2L9xRnHjJiAK76m2BIEaSEV+/aU" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="icons">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook" alt="facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter" alt="twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
</div>
```

---

Addendum: Yes, you can use `first-child` and `last-child` as pointed in other answers. I did write my answer under the assumption that there will be more icons, and the presented code is just a minimun example. Yet, if you only need two, feel free to use `first-child` and `last-child`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a [pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes).

For example, one way to solve your problem would be:

`.icons a:first-child {}` and `.icons a:last-child {}`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **pseudo elements** `:first-child`, `:last-child` and of course `:nth-child(x)` if you have more than 2 children. Check below snippet for reference.

```css
.icons a:first-child {
  color: red;
}

.icons a:nth-child(2) {
  color: green;
}

.icons a:nth-child(3) {
  color: cyan;
}

.icons a:last-child {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="icons">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook" alt="facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter" alt="twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="fa fa-facebook" alt="facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/" class="fa fa-twitter" alt="twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

One thing you can try is to iterate over them using jQuery:

```
$(".icons a").each(function(index, element){
     //index is the current element index
     //element is the a tag
});
```

Comment: He wants to style the a-tags differently. Why the hell do some people see jQuery as the solution for everything in the world :D